# SQL reduce number of columns in inner query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query:

```
select  
    count(*), paymentOptionId 
from 
    payments 
where 
    id in (select min(reportDate), id 
           from payments 
           where userId in (select distinct userId 
                            from payments 
                            where paymentOptionId in (46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56)) 
           group by userId)
group by 
    paymentOptionId;
```

The problem place is "select min(reportDate), id", this query must return 1 column result, but I can't realize how to do it while I need to group min.

The data set looks like

```
+----+--------+--------+-----------+---------------------+--------+----------+-----------------+
| id | userId | amount | userLevel | reportDate          | buffId | bankQuot | paymentOptionId |
+----+--------+--------+-----------+---------------------+--------+----------+-----------------+
|  9 |  12012 |      5 |         5 | 2014-02-10 23:07:57 |   NULL |     NULL |               2 |
| 10 |  12191 |      5 |         6 | 2014-02-10 23:52:12 |   NULL |     NULL |               2 |
| 11 |  12295 |      5 |         6 | 2014-02-11 00:12:04 |   NULL |     NULL |               2 |
| 12 |  12295 |      5 |         6 | 2014-02-11 00:12:42 |   NULL |     NULL |               2 |
| 13 |  12256 |      5 |         6 | 2014-02-11 00:26:25 |   NULL |     NULL |               2 |
| 14 |  12256 |      5 |         6 | 2014-02-11 00:26:35 |   NULL |     NULL |               2 |
| 16 |  12510 |      5 |         5 | 2014-02-11 00:42:58 |   NULL |     NULL |               2 |
| 17 |  12510 |      5 |         5 | 2014-02-11 00:43:08 |   NULL |     NULL |               2 |
| 18 |  12510 |     18 |         5 | 2014-02-11 00:45:16 |   NULL |     NULL |               3 |
| 19 |  12510 |      5 |         6 | 2014-02-11 01:00:10 |   NULL |     NULL |               2 |
+----+--------+--------+-----------+---------------------+--------+----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: What do you want your query to do?  There may be other ways to express it.

Comment: Please post example input and the result you want to achieve.

Comment: wana count number of first(by userId) entries grouped by type.

Comment: What type? Do you mean paymentOptionId? And if so, what would be the example result for the above dataset that you wish to get?

Comment: paymentOptionId = 2 | count = 5 |

Sry. Right - number of first payments of users grouped by paymentOptionId

Comment: Check answer below (and fiddle), seems like it's giving you results you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select count(*), paymentOptionId
    from 
        (select userId, min(reportdate), paymentOptionId 
            from payments as t1 
            group by userId, paymentOptionId) as t2 
    group by paymentOptionId
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf3a3/11)

It first gets the minimum report date (so the first entry) for every user, for every type (so there are two records for a user who has 2 types) and then counts them grouping by type (aka paymentOptionId).

By the way, you can of course cut the attributes chosen in `select` in `from` clause, they are only there so you can copy-paste it and see the results it is giving step by step.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to report on various payment options and their counts for the earliest `ReportDate` for each user.

If so, here is an alternative approach

```
select p.paymentOptionId, count(*) 
from payments p
where paymentOptionId in (46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from payments p2
                  where p2.userId = p.userId and
                        p2.ReportDate < p.ReportDate
                 )
group by paymentOptionId;
```

This isn't exactly the same as your query, because this will only report on the list of payment types, whereas you might want the first payment type for anyone who has ever had one of these types.  I'm not sure which you want, though.

Comment: The goal is to count entries of types of first payments of users. So this query not really hit it.